# Kotlin email not sending

Tags: android, kotlin, email, gmail

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/sendEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:onClick="sendMail"
        android:text="Send"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
```

This is a button in my activity.main.xml
It calls the sendEmail function in my MainActivity.kt when clicked

```
fun sendMail(view: View) {
        val username = "email"
        val password = "password"

        val properties = Properties()
        properties["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true"
        properties["mail.smtp.starttls.enable"] = "true"
        properties["mail.smtp.host"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
        properties["mail.smtp.port"] = "587"

        val session = Session.getInstance(properties, object : Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                return PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
            }
        })

        try {
            val message = MimeMessage(session)
            message.setFrom(InternetAddress(username))
            message.addRecipient(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress("email")
            )
            message.subject = "Subject of the Email"
            message.setText("Test message.")

            Transport.send(message)

            println("Email has been sent to whoever.")
        } catch (e: MessagingException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

```
Transport.send(message)
```

is where the app crashes, everything before that works fine.

[When I run MainActivityKt, the code above will work in the main function. When running app or MainActivity it calls the sendMail function and gives an error at Transport.send(message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9QKj.png)

Im new to both Kotlin (and even Android Studio) and sending emails. Thanks in advance!

When running the main function with this code, it will send the email perfectly:

```
val username = "email"
        val password = "password"

        val properties = Properties()
        properties["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true"
        properties["mail.smtp.starttls.enable"] = "true"
        properties["mail.smtp.host"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
        properties["mail.smtp.port"] = "587"

        val session = Session.getInstance(properties, object : Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                return PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
            }
        })

        try {
            val message = MimeMessage(session)
            message.setFrom(InternetAddress(username))
            message.addRecipient(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress("email")
            )
            message.subject = "Subject of the Email"
            message.setText("Test message.")

            Transport.send(message)

            println("Email has been sent to whoever.")
        } catch (e: MessagingException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

When not running the Kotlin file directly, it does somehow not work?

Comment: If your app crashes you did not catch an exception that was thrown. Use the logcat to find out which one.

Comment: `When not running the Kotlin file directly` ? I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Further it seems -at first glance- that you posted the same code twice. Confusing.

Comment: Can you please share the crash logs? Your code seems good. It might be possible that the crash is due to long network operation on the Main thread.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry about the duplicated code, I thought it'd be more clear than confusing. I changed the catch block to ```catch (e: Error)``` and it does not crash anymore, thanks for that.

Anyway, the code works if I run the kotlin file, but if I run 'app' or 'MainActivity' in the image, the email does not send.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved I just solved the crashing issue, the catch block was incorrect. I changed it to: 
```catch (e: Error) {
    println(e)
}```
Output:
```java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;```

Comment: `the code works if I run the kotlin file, but if I run 'app' or 'MainActivity' in the image, the email does not send.` ?? I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @blackapps ```Transport.send(message)``` gives an error when the function is called from the click of the button. When I just run it, it works fine.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean or do with just running simething.